# Passing string via pointer - incompatible argument

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to pass two strings to a function that copies the second string into the first string. Get the error messages

```
"passing arguement 1/2 of 'CopyStrings'from incompatible pointer type - line 25.
note: expected 'char*' but argument is of type 'char**' - line 8
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// a function that gets 2 strings and copies the second one into the first one


char CopyStrings(char* string1, char* string2)
{
  strcpy(string1, string2);

  return *string1;

}

int main()
{
  char* string1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
  char* string2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

  strcpy(string1, "ugabuga");
  strcpy(string2, "mukaluka");


  printf("%s", CopyStrings(string1, string2));


  free(string1);
  free(string2);
  return 0;

}
```

Any suggestions what I messed up and how I write the pointers correctly?

EDIT - Now that I changed

```
(&string1, &string2)
```

into

```
(string1, string2)
```

the program chrashes.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc` in C. Also, you obviously are asking for the address of the `char *` by doing `&string1` in the function call, which passes a `char **`.

Comment: Ah true. Can you explain why I should not use malloc here?

Comment: use malloc != cast malloc. Casting malloc is not needed and iirc it suppresses some kind of warning, but I'm not exactly sure. It's discouraged.

Comment: @Yíu You shouldn't *cast* the result from `malloc`, as it will make your code compile (and probably crash badly) if you forgot to include its header. (It's unnecessary to use too in this case, as you can just write `char string1[10];` and get rid of `free`).

Comment: Hmm okay. But in this example I think casting malloc is okay as the program runs fine if I exclude the function /* and just printf my strings.

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()` for the reasons herein listed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problems with the OPs code:

In the following code, most of the problems are commented (and fixed)
One thing to know, in C, an array name degrades to the address of the array try to always pass pointer to array rather than the complete array the `%s` conversion operator is expecting the associated parameter to be the address of a char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// a function that gets 2 strings and copies the second one into the first one


char* CopyStrings(char* string1, char* string2)
{
  strcpy(string1, string2);
  return string1; // return pointer to string1
}

int main()
{
  char* string1 = malloc(10);  // char is always 1 so no need for sizeof(char)
  char* string2 = malloc(10);

  strcpy(string1, "ugabuga");
  strcpy(string2, "mukaluka");

  printf("%s\n", CopyStrings(string1, string2));

  free(string1);
  free(string2);
  return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate. But since a char pointer is equal to an array it kinda does make sense to allocate memory for it - or am I wrong?

Comment: @Yiu you're right. Whether it is char array or pointer to char, memory allocation is must but first case can be compilation time and later one allocates at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You really want just

```
CopyStrings(string1, string2)
```

It's `char*` already, and you're making `char**` from it with the ampersand.

Another problem is in your function - it should be:

```
char* CopyStrings(char* string1, char* string2)
{
    strcpy(string1, string2);
    return string1;
}
```

(if you want to return the first string).

Answer (score 1):

Change

`CopyStrings(&string1, &string2)`

to

`CopyStrings(string1, string2)`

`char* string1`, here `string1` is a pointer and when you pass address if pointer which is pointer to pointer, its not what you mean and formal arguments should be double pointers. Passing just the pointer is sufficient.

The `CopyStrings()` function need to return a `char *` string after performing strcpy() to caller. Here is the modified [code](http://ideone.com/RUFxQU).

Comment: Okay thanks. I've changed that, but the program still crashes. :/